# can you stop users viewing draft changes to sharepoint list items without having content approval set to yes

Tags: list

If I wanted to only allow certain users to view draft changes to a Sharepoint List (not doclib), but not want to go through a content approval workflow, is this possible please?

I've set in versioning settings:

Require content approval for submitted items? to No
Create a version each time you edit an item in the list to Yes

but in Draft Item Security, I only get the option for who should see draft items in the list to be "Any user who can read items". I wanted to change this to be Only Users who can edit items". This second option is greyed out.